# Stripe webhook versioning exception in test mode

Tags: .net-core, stripe-payments

I am trying to test to send a `charge.succeeded` webhook to my endpoint but there's an error:

 **`Received event with API version 2019-03-14, but Stripe.net 24.5.0 expects API version 2019-02-19`** 
 and when adding webhook in test mode you can only choose `2019-03-14` or `2018-11-08` version.

[image: versions]

Obviously I'm using Stripe.net 24.5.0, I can't test my webhook because of this.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I found the answer [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/1556).

You just need to set the `throwOnApiVersionMismatch` to `false` and it will not check the version if it's not the same.

sample code:

```
var event = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(
              JSON,
              Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"],
              _secret,
              300,
              (long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds,
              false);
```

EDIT: As stated by karllekko and in the [link](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/1556) it is much safer to create a WebhookEndpoint with the  API version forced to the same API version as the library, this can only be done via API and not in the dashboard.

Comment: This is bad idea though. The real solution is call the API and create an endpoint that is pinned to "2019-02-19", the version that stripe-dotnet expects : https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/create#create_webhook_endpoint-api_version You can do this through the API, but not the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your current webhook and create a new webhook with the same url, but change the API version. Stripe 24.5.0 expects API version 2019-02-19 but you are supplying the default API which is 2018-11-08 in the webhook - which will throw an error.

Change to the required API and test your webhook again. This also goes for future API releases - be sure to use the latest API if you experience this error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you perhaps hardcode the API version to "2019-02-19" in your application?

You can downgrade your API key version to "2019-02-19" but you'll have to write into Stripe support to do that: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't hard code anything in the API I just upgraded to version `24.5.0` then when I tried to send a webhook it will throw that error. I'll try to contact support. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Head over to https://dashboard.stripe.com/developers
At the bottom of the page Click the "Upgrade" button and choose the latest version.
That's it.